# giving a sharepoint online communication site anonymous access

Tags: sharepoint-online, anonymous-access

I'm creating a sharepoint online site destined to be for outside customers.
I would like it to be a site with anonymous access.
Can't find anything to do that.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not possible** anymore (since 2018) to open SharePoint Online site to anonymous users.

As an alternative, you can:

- Use [Power Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-pages/security/site-visibility) which allow anonymous user
- Use [SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview) with external users (users are not part of your organization, but managed as guests and authenticated in your Entra ID)

Source: [SharePoint Online Public Websites to be discontinued](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/public-websites-be-discontinued)

Comment: Ok.got it.  Thank you!